# Windows 10 alarm with option to silence / dismiss after specified time

Tags: windows-10, alarm-clock

The built-in Windows 10 Alarm does not have the option to silence / dismiss the alarm after a specified period of time (AFAIK). This is an issue when an alarm is scheduled as repeatable every day, re: if the computer is left on / locked, the alarm will go off endlessly until manually dismissed.

Bare Minimum Feature Set:

- Repeat settings, i.e., can be programmed for M-F at x time
- Support for multiple alarms
- Display notification when triggered
- Setting to silence / dismiss the alarm after x time
- Nice to have: snooze

Deal Breakers:

- Bloatware such as music app, world clocks, weather, etc...
- In-app Ads
- In-app nagware that cannot be dismissed
- Costs more than $10 (U.S.)

Comment: Not sure any support what you mean but have a look at [Hourglass](https://chris.dziemborowicz.com/apps/hourglass) and [Digital CLock 4](https://sourceforge.net/projects/digitalclock4/)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos - Looks like Hourglass is just a timer, no alarm. Digital Clock 4 looks interesting; I couldn't find a full feature-set, though. have you used it?

Comment: Just tested them for a bit, but never used them for any extended period of time. It has an alarm, though I didn't see any dismiss options. It has a portable standalone though so no need to install if you want to check it out